# Split Characters in String With Defined Character Length

Tags: php, html

I have a constraint when creating a form to display values in a table column horizontally based on characters in php. Like the example below. How to separate each character according to column?

```html
<div style="display:inline;">
Name : 
<table style="display:inline; position:absolute" width="400" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="28"><div align="center">I</div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center">R</div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center">W</div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center">A</div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center">N</div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center"></div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center">D</div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center">W</div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center">I</div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center"></div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center"></div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center"></div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center"></div></td>
    <td width="28"><div align="center"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You're looking for [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php). It will turn your string into an array of letters, then you can loop through that array.

Comment: show us some example of what you expecting  *How to separate each character according to column* ??

Comment: Thanks @Luke His advice was very helpful

Comment: thanks @AbdullaNilam for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you define 14 chars for the string. So, when string length lower than 14, it will be filled empty character. Please try this

```
<?php
define('TEXT_LENGTH', 14);
$string = 'IRAWAN DWI';
$formattedText = str_pad($string, TEXT_LENGTH, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT); 
$arrayText =  str_split($formattedText);
?>

<div style="display:inline;">
Name : 
<table style="display:inline; position:absolute" width="400" border="1">
  <tr>
    <?php foreach ($arrayText as $char): ?>
      <td width="28"><div align="center"><?php echo $char; ?></div></td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is what i hope for thank you for the answer ... this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to separate characters from a string and insert them horizontally into your table then this php function can solve the problem

```
function sep($str){
$leng = strlen($str);
echo '<div style="display:inline;">';
echo 'Name :' 
echo '<table style="display:inline; position:absolute" width="400" border="1"><tr>';
for ($i=0;$i<= $leng-1;$i++){
    $chr = substr($srt,$i,1);
    echo '<td width="28"><div align="center">'.$chr.'</div></td>';
    }
    echo   '</tr></table></div>';
}
```

you just call the function from your php

```
sep('IRWAN DWI');
```

or if you dont want to call a function just add this code

```
    <?php 
    $str = IRWAN DWI';  
    $leng = strlen($str);
    echo '<div style="display:inline;">';
    echo 'Name :' 
    echo '<table style="display:inline; position:absolute" width="400" border="1"><tr>';
    for ($i=0;$i<= $leng-1;$i++){
            $chr = substr($srt,$i,1);
            echo '<td width="28"><div align="center">'.$chr.'</div></td>';
    }
    echo   '</tr></table></div>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashraf D, Milhim for the answer ... this is helpful but Dolly Aswin's answer is a bit perfect